# Tests fail when renaming identifiers, etc

Tags: rust

I've got a large repo in which I noticed that some tests started failing after I added a dependency to Cargo.toml, despite the dependency never being referenced. I began to investigate, and was able to reproduce the problem consistently in [this repo](https://github.com/CGamesPlay/libsqlite3-sys-err). I'll reproduce the code of the main file here:

```rust
mod test {
    pub fn b<T>(db: *mut libsqlite3_sys::sqlite3, _: T) {
        let rc = unsafe {
            libsqlite3_sys::sqlite3_create_function(
                db,                   // db
                "x".as_ptr() as _,    // zFunction
                0,                    // nArg
                0,                    // eTextRep
                std::ptr::null_mut(), // pApp
                None,                 // xFunc
                None,                 // xStep
                None,                 // xFinal
            )
        };
        match rc {
            libsqlite3_sys::SQLITE_MISUSE => (),
            x => panic!("Wanted SQLITE_MISUSE, got {:?}", x),
        }
    }
}

#[test]
#[ignore]
fn z() {
    format!("{:?}", &[1, 2, 3, 4]);
    panic!("not run");
}

#[test]
fn a() {
    const FILENAME: &[u8] = b":memory:\0";
    let mut db: *mut libsqlite3_sys::sqlite3 = std::ptr::null_mut();
    let rc = unsafe { libsqlite3_sys::sqlite3_open(FILENAME.as_ptr() as _, &mut db) };
    assert_eq!(rc, libsqlite3_sys::SQLITE_OK);
    test::b(db, 0);
}
```

On my computer, these tests pass, meaning that sqlite3_create_function is returning SQLITE_MISUSE.

```
$ cargo test --lib --features=static
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.52s
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/sqlite3_ext-5449511dde1f34ef)

running 2 tests
test z ... ignored
test a ... ok

test result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 1 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.01s
```

Now, it shouldn't be returning MISUSE, because as far as I can tell everything about this code is valid. However, here's where it gets weird:

- If I don't use `--features=static`, the test fails. Note that nothing references this feature whatsoever.
- If I remove the `format!` line, the test fails. Note that the code is never called.
- If I add or remove any dependencies to Cargo.toml, the test fails. None of the changes are referenced anywhere in the code.
- If I rename the feature "static" to anything else, the test fails.
- If I rename the module "test" to anything else, the test fails.
- If I run this code on Linux, the test fails.

I am able to add `[features] joke = []` to Cargo.toml, and then I get this behavior:

- `cargo test --lib --features=joke` fails (no MISUSE)
- `cargo test --lib --features=static` passes (MISUSE)
- `cargo test --lib --features=static,joke` fails (no MISUSE)

I am at my wit's end. I am running macOS 10.14.6 (18G9323), rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18). Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've also [uploaded binaries](https://github.com/CGamesPlay/libsqlite3-sys-err/releases/tag/v0.0) to GitHub for investigation if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @thomcc who responded on the rusqlite Discord:

> you’re not passing a nul-terminated string to c for one

This was the issue. In most cases the only problem this caused was that my application-defined function was never removed, but in this particular case it resulted in an SQLITE_MISUSE being returned. Properly converting my `&str` to `CString` resolves the issue.